# tkinter grid not resizing based on window size

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid, resize

So I have come across something I defiantly cant figure out and need help. I have 2 buttons that both send you to the next frame and they work just fine but when I resize the window they stay the same size and stay in the upper left corner and I want them to place them selves in the center of the screen. If there is an example as to them growing as well, that would also be appreciated but not necessary. Also I would like to stick with grid if possible.
I tried columnconfigure and placing the frame in another frame, nothing i do seems to work. Strangely tho if I replace container with self and drop the self on the buttons it works but with out the command working, can someone explain this to me or give me a good example as to what I'm doing wrong?

Sample of code:

```
import tkinter as tk
class MYapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.frames = {}
        for FRAME in (N1, N2):
            frame = FRAME(container, self)
            self.frames[FRAME] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(N1)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
class N1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        a = tk.Button(self, text = "N1", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(N2))
        a.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        c = tk.Button(self, text = "N1", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(N2))
        c.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")
class N2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        b = tk.Button(self, text = "N2")
        b.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MYapp()
    app.mainloop()
```

SOLVED:
Thanks to Bryan.
This is the updated code with the answer in place.

```
import tkinter as tk
class MYapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frames = {}
        for FRAME in (N1, N2):
            frame = FRAME(container, self)
            self.frames[FRAME] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
            frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
            frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
            frame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.show_frame(N1)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
class N1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        a = tk.Button(self, text = "N1", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(N2))
        a.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        c = tk.Button(self, text = "N1", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(N2))
        c.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")
class N2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        b = tk.Button(self, text = "N2")
        b.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MYapp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You said they stay the same size, and stay in the upper left corner, but you didn't state what you want them to do. Should they be centered? Grow with the window? Stay at the top? Stay at the bottom? Put the extra space in the middle?

Comment: my apologies, i'll update my question. I wanted them to be centered. also an example to them growing as well would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't way what the preferred behavior is, only that what it's doing is wrong. I don't know if this suggestion will do what you want or not.

As a rule of thumb, when you use `grid` you should always give at least one row and one column a weight for the parent containing the widgets being managed. While  you do that for widgets in the container, you don't do it for the root window. Therefore, widgets *inside* the container might be resizing properly, but you won't see it because the container itself isn't resizing.

If you're only going to put a single widget inside another widget, I recommend using `pack` because you can do everything in a single line of code. Therefore, I recommend using `pack` rather than `grid` for the container itself:

```
container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Also, since your container seems to only have a single row and a single column, you probably don't want to give column 1 a weight.

Finally, you are also using `grid` to manage the widgets inside each page (`N1`, `N2`), but again, you are forgetting to give a weight to any rows or columns inside those frames.

Comment: I see what I did wrong, I think, I replaced the container.grid with the pack line you gave, then I added weight to the frame.grid and so far it works perfect with the sample. Thanks Bryan.

Answer (score 0):

The grid function keeps them where they are.  You could use the pack function which could help you.  It's just something that Tkinter doesn't do easily.