# ttk Notebook not expanding with grid geometry manager

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid, tabcontrol

I cannot work out how to have a ttk Notebook widget expand correctly when the GUI is resized using the .grid method in tk. It is straightforward in .pack, I have tried some sticky configuration methods and they don't see to do anything useful.

***Code***

```
import tkinter as tk                     
from tkinter import ttk 

root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry("500x350") 
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
 
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')

tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")
#tabControl.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky= tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

root.mainloop()
```

***Desired Outcome***

A gui that can be stretched and have the tab control and frame resize with the new  window size.

Comment: This link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898749/tkinter-grid-not-resizing-based-on-window-size

Comment: If `pack` is working for you, why not use `pack`? You can do it with `grid` but it requires more code.

Comment: This is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do and need the control over what comes later using the grid manager.

Comment: The problem I have is that in my code using pack when I want to add a navigation toolbar to the plot I have in the tab using grid I get this error:   _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!notebook.!frame2 which already has slaves managed by grid.        so I was trying to redo my code without the pack geometry manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grids, by default, shrink.  If you more pack-like behavior, you must give the cells 'weight.'  It's pretty easy to do:

```
import tkinter as tk                     
from tkinter import ttk 

root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry("500x350") 
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
 
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')

tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
tabControl.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

root.mainloop()
```

That should do it.  Let us know if you have more questions etc.